# Update на БД c if условием

Tags: mysql

```
update 
 products_shop
set
 (int)active = 1
where ( select (int)id_product from products where (int)reference = 111111111)
```

а потом добавить `if`

```
if(reference == true and active = 0)
 active = 1
else 
 active = 0
```

Вопрос можно ли реализовать такое на чистом sql или все придеться проверять select'ом а потом если что апдейтить?

Comment: 1. так `reference` должно быть  `111111111` или `true`? 2. `active` принимает значения только `0` или `1`?

Comment: reference int значение  , active только 0 выккл 1 вкл

Comment: *reference int значение* — тогда, пожалуйста, сформулируйте вопрос более чётко и однозначно. отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: тогда поясните, пожалуйста, что означает `if(reference == true`.

Comment: это я описал процесс отбора значений из бд и изменение значений из определеных условия

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, **словами**, какие строки таблицы вам требуется обновлять и при каких условиях.

Comment: смотри в чем соль, раньше это делалось так, выключалось все и включалось, только то что нашло reference все те id"шники, я вот и подумал зачем отрубать все если можно подставить так что бы если нашло reference и он active 1 то иди дальше , если reference не нашло active этому товару поставить , если reference нашло и active = 0 то поставить 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я всё-таки правильно понял изложенное в вопросе и комментариях, то требуется, видимо, что-то в этом духе:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/763bf/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table shop (id int, product int, active int);
create table products (product int, reference int);

insert into shop values
  (1, 1, 0)
  ,(2, 1, 1)
  ,(3, 2, 0)
  ,(4, 2, 1)
;

insert into products values
  (1, 0), (2, 1);

update shop
left join products
on products.product = shop.product
and products.reference = 1
set shop.active = if(products.product is null, 0, 1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from shop
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/763bf/3/0)**:

```
| id | product | active |
|----|---------|--------|
|  1 |       1 |      0 |
|  2 |       1 |      0 |
|  3 |       2 |      1 |
|  4 |       2 |      1 |
```

Comment: да очень очень похоже на правду, спасибо большое.

Comment: а есть ли вариант лимита , ограничить включение товара только первого который нашла, понятно что через limit но вот куда его всунуть что бы заработало

Comment: извините, не понял вопроса. ведь изначально вам, вроде бы, требовалось изменять **все** записи в таблице. если требуются какие-то ограничения на основании других полей этой же таблицы, которую вы изменяете, добавьте директиву where: `update ... join ... on ... and ... where какие-то-условия set ...`.

Comment: если же вы не понимаете, как составить эти условия, задайте, пожалуйста, **новый** вопрос, в котором изложите словами, что вам ещё требуется, а также в новом вопросе стоит привести схему ваших таблиц и, возможно, ссылку на **этот** вопрос.

Comment: схему таблицы можно получить, например, командой `describe имя-таблицы`

Comment: блин мужик ты гений, у меня апдейт занимал 15 мин, с твоим запросом 4 секунды. умоляю скажи как ты так научился?

Comment: @MsimЙопт, сразу же после того, как вы расскажете, **как** у вас получилось написать **такой** update, который работает **так** долго (в сравнении с «обычным»).

Comment: просто применял update к отдельной части например update product set active = 1 where reference = 2425343 . и таких записей получалось соответственно много. я лазил предворително искав варианты решения задачи более быстрые , например через where IN записать но получалось все равно не так быстро

Comment: в общем спасибо тебе что показал новый путь, пошел зубрить мат часть.

Comment: @MsimЙопт, делюсь «секретом»: вероятно, вам недостаёт теоретических представлений о том, что такое [реляционная модель данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). по ссылке есть упоминания книг Дейта и Кодда. в своё время (лет эдак 15, а то и 20 назад) я их прочёл (и не только их) и получил общее представление. а позже — уже практика.